# Why does stopService only work on one device?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, service

When the user leaves my application, stopService () is executed so that the service that is playing the music stops running, however, if I use my app on my phone, it works perfectly, if I use it on another phone like mine (exactly the same, android, model) it doesn't work anymore. Is there any plausible explanation for this?

```
@OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP)
private void onAppBackgrounded() {
    Log.d("MyApp", "App in background");

    if (!premiumState) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("Preferences", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putString("initialize_player_before_exit", "ok");
        editor.putString("message_for_free_user", "ok");
        editor.apply();

        Intent intent = new Intent(InicioActivity.this, AudioPlayerService.class);
        stopService(intent);
    }
}

@OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_START)
private void onAppForegrounded() {
    Log.d("MyApp", "App in foreground");
}
```

Comment: No. Absolutely no reason. Sounds super strange. Add some logging and examine logcat on the other phone.

Comment: It seems that on other phones he doesn't recognize that the service is running. However, I still don't understand how it works on my cell phone and not on another one, is there any permission or compilation that I must use in order to solve this problem?

Comment: I also discovered another problem that occurs, now I have 2 problems that do not occur in my cell phone and in another one exactly the same occurs, I find this very unfortunate, I am at 20H without stopping looking for a resolution and all that I find work, but only in MY cell phone

Comment: In addition, I looked at the logcat and did not show anything different from one cell phone to another, which becomes more incomprehensible to me